# Prometheus Query - Average of a Metric, for a specific period of time

Tags: prometheus

I've been working with Prometheus lately, and I am trying to find an efficient way to calculate the average of a metric based on a _sum and _count. The metric has many labels, so I am using the query below to sum without (x,y,x) and then dividing that by the sum of another metric to see the average for a start / end time.

My approach so far is

1. Find the increases in the metric, between 2 time periods (24 hours)
2. Sum of the file_process_time_seconds_sum increases would be the total for the period
3. Sum of the file_processing_time_secounds_count increases is the number of entires
4. divide the 2 results
5. Obtain the answer

The query receives the following

1. Query (outlined below) as a query_range
2. start = 1628308800  (August 7th @ 12:00:00am) GMT-4
3. end   = 1628395200  (August 8th @ 12:00:00am) GMT-4
4. step  = 1d

```
sum(
  sum(
     increase(
      {
        application_name="ic-file-transfer",
        __name__="file_processing_time_seconds_sum"
      }[1d]
     )
  ) 
/ 
  sum(
     increase(
      {
        application_name="ic-file-transfer",
        __name__="file_processing_time_seconds_count"
      }[1d]
     )
  )
)
```

When I run this query, I obtain the following result

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "resultType": "matrix",
        "result": [
            {
                "metric": {},
                "values": [
                    [
                        1628308800,
                        "8.701666666666666"
                    ],
                    [
                        1628395200,
                        "4.981652471617543"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

1. I read the first result as the average of the increases that occurred for the time ending August 7th @ 12:00:00am
2. I read the second result as the average of the increaes that occured for the time ending August 8th @ 12:00:00am (so the results of the previous day given the step is 1d)

Questions

1. Am I interpurting the results correctly?
2. Is this a valid way to calculate the average of a value?

Thanks, apologies for the very long winded questions.

Note:
The query string looks like the following:

```
{{metric_host}}/query_range?query=sum(sum(increase({application_name="ic-file-transfer",__name__="file_processing_time_seconds_sum"}[1d])) / sum(increase({application_name="ic-file-transfer",__name__="file_processing_time_seconds_count"}[1d])))&start=1628308800&end=1628395200&step=1d
```

Comment: Isn't it tbe case to use `avg_over_time` as the docs say `avg_over_time(range-vector): the average value of all points in the specified interval.`? I see that you have 2 different metrics. However they are sum and count based on the same range vector.

Comment: I will try the avg_over_time, thanks for the suggestion.